# Convergence/Divergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}(3^{1/n^2} -1) \csc^2n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}(3^{1/n^2} -1) \csc^2n$

It's obviously a positive series and the parts of $\csc^2n $ tells me it might be divergent. But I have no idea how to prove it. Any one can offer some help or hints?

Comment: Please see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4075392/72031).

Comment: Thank you! I've been searching for quite a while. I'll take a quick look

Comment: The only answer in the other question is pretty much what I thought, The potential divergence of the series comes from the occasional but irrational spikes provided by $csc^2(n)$, but it's still of little help for a rigorous proof.

Comment: You can see that the problem essentially needs information on irrationality measure of $\pi$ and I am not sure if the problem has been solved or not.

Comment: hmm nope, I still have no idea how to prove the series is divergent..